# Firebug 1.12.5 - Can the Console "password fields..insecure..." message be supressed?

Tags: firebug

Can the console message: "Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen." be suppressed? If it can - how?

I haven't used firebug for a while and this new check has been added in a recent version.

(My answer to the message is "yes I already know, stop going on about it!!!")

Answer (score 4):

1. This message isn't generated by Firebug but by Firefox. Firebug just displays it in its *Console* panel. See [bug 762593](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762593).
2. It's currently (Firebug 2.0.4) not possible in Firebug to hide specific log messages. You may want to follow [Issue 4368](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4368), which is asking for this feature.

Sebastian